# Unity - The name 'auth' does not exist in the current context

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I am currently trying to create user authentication in unity and I am having some issues.
The code below is what I have at the moment and I keep receiving the error saying Auth does not exist in the current context.

Does anyone have any idea why this is? Probably a simple fix that I am just overlooking.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Auth;

public class Register : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject email;
    public GameObject password;
    public GameObject confPassword;
    private string Email;
    private string Password;
    private string ConfPassword;
    private string form;
    private bool EmailValid = false;
    private string[] Characters = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
                                   "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
                                   "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","_","-"};

    public void RegisterButton(){
        bool EM = false;
        bool PW = false;
        bool CPW = false;

        if (Email != ""){
            EmailValidation();
            if (EmailValid){
                if(Email.Contains("@")){
                    if(Email.Contains(".")){
                        EM = true;
                    } else {
                        Debug.LogWarning("Email is Incorrect");
                    }
                } else {
                    Debug.LogWarning("Email is Incorrect");
                }
            } else {
                Debug.LogWarning("Email is Incorrect");
            }
        } else {
            Debug.LogWarning("Email Field Empty");
        }
        if (Password != ""){
            if(Password.Length > 5){
                PW = true;
            } else {
                Debug.LogWarning("Password Must Be atleast 6 Characters long");
            }
        } else {
            Debug.LogWarning("Password Field Empty");
        }
        if (ConfPassword != ""){
            if (ConfPassword == Password){
                CPW = true;
            } else {
                Debug.LogWarning("Passwords Don't Match");
            }
        } else {
            Debug.LogWarning("Confirm Password Field Empty");
        }
        if (EM == true&&PW == true&&CPW == true)
        {
            auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsCanceled) {
                Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
            return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted) {
                Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
            return;
        }

        // Firebase user has been created.
        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
        Debug.LogFormat("Firebase user created successfully: {0} ({1})",
        newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
        });
        }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab)){
            if (email.GetComponent<InputField>().isFocused){
                password.GetComponent<InputField>().Select();
            }
            if (password.GetComponent<InputField>().isFocused){
                confPassword.GetComponent<InputField>().Select();
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return)){
            if (Password != ""&&Email != ""&&Password != ""&&ConfPassword != ""){
                RegisterButton();
            }
        }
        Email = email.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
        Password = password.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
        ConfPassword = confPassword.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
    }

    void EmailValidation(){
        bool SW = false;
        bool EW = false;
        for(int i = 0;i<Characters.Length;i++){
            if (Email.StartsWith(Characters[i])){
                SW = true;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<Characters.Length;i++){
            if (Email.EndsWith(Characters[i])){
                EW = true;
            }
        }
        if(SW == true&&EW == true){
            EmailValid = true;
        } else {
            EmailValid = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see you ever creating the variable `auth`?

While you refer to it here:

```
auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task =>
```

So I assume you will have to create a variable `auth` and instantiate it with something related to `FireBase.Auth` (unless I am overlooking something).

Comment: I have just added that in, now my error is telling me 
Argument cannot convert from UnityEngine.GameObject to String

Do you happen to know why this is?

Comment: Hm, It's difficult to tell from your message what exactly is happening, as you did give the extra code you just wrote,

However, it means that you are trying to put a ```GameObject``` somewhere where a string is expected, as parameter.

Comment: the line of code i added was
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;

My error is now :  Argument cannot convert from UnityEngine.GameObject to String

Comment: The Unity log window should provide you with the location of the code and the exact function where it happens. That is the critical in order to find the error. Somewhere you are using a ```GameObject``` as parameter, where a string is expected. Scanning your code above here (quicky), I do not see any code where that happens. So maybe it is somewhere else?

Comment: Ahh i found it, the lovely mixing up of small and capital letters!

Thank you!